# Can not bind within resource dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm running a simple MVVM project and fallen at the first hurdle. I'm binding my commands using Josh Smiths Relay Command approach.

The problem is, the button isn't binding when the button is in the ResourceDictionary. If I move the code (exactly as is) into my MainWindow.xaml then the code executes as desired.

This is my MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ForJon.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ForJon.Ui.ViewModels"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="160" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\ResourceDictionary.xaml" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <HeaderedContentControl
        Header="Options"
        Style="{StaticResource LeftMenu}" 
        Grid.Column="0"
        / >

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the resource dictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:ForJon.Ui.Views"
                    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ForJon.Ui.ViewModels"
                    >

    <Style x:Key="LeftMenu" TargetType="HeaderedContentControl">
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="160"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

I can only assume that when binding in the ResourceDictionary that it can't find the ViewModel (although I don't know why I think that). I think it's trying to bind an extra level down...

Any way, can some one explain why it's not executing from within the Resource Dictionary please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue seems to have not much to do with the ResourceDictionary than having the parent `DataContext` pass to the `DataTemplate`

If you copy the `Style` and put it into the `Grid.Resources` and comment the resource dictionary the same behavior can be seen. Also turning on Binding errors should show

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'AddCommand' property not found on 'object' ''String'
```

Fix is pretty much get the `DataContext` through.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Style x:Key="LeftMenu"
         TargetType="HeaderedContentControl">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
      <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type HeaderedContentControl}}, Path=DataContext}">
            <Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
                    Content="Add" />
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="160" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

same issue applies to `ContentTemplate` but `Template` works fine(It uses a `ControlTemplate`)

```
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
      <StackPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
                Content="Add" />
      </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: This solves the issue but surely there must be a more elegant approach than what I've done? Would it be better to declare the DataContext in the Resource Dictionary instead? Thank you!

Comment: @DaveRook Getting the DataContext via a RelativeSource binding isn't bad at all when you know what your doing. However if you ask for my personal opinion I wouldn't do either. Concept of resource dictionary is for us to reuse control's but when we have binding's in the resource dictionary you've basically tied the `Style` down to a very specific VM & View which means you might have been better off defining it in the Item itself directly.

Comment: Wow, Viv, thank you. Beers on me for this. Yes, I can see why you'd take this approach, this is truly excellent and a massive help.

Comment: @DaveRook if I intend to use this `HeaderedContentControl` in multiple views with same `Style`, I'd subclass the `HeaderedContentControl` add a DP to it and define the Style now in a resource Dictionary and in the command binding I'd make it bind to the DP. That way in any of the View's that I'm using this control, I'd just specify the command from the VM in the actual View's xaml for the DP and my `Style` would be setup accordingly to work with that

Comment: @Viv What you're saying about Views and Resource Dictionaries is correct, but what about localization?? (the concept of styling same controls giving them the localization capability has its own sense in my opinion...and in this case there aren't a lot of possibilities...). What do you think?

Comment: @MAXE Not too sure I follow your question correctly, why does localisation limit your possibilities in any way? Have localisation approached via something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files) and then bind your localisation keys in the View's where you are using them or override them if you set them in `Style` as defaults

Comment: @Viv Sorry...I didn't notice that the question is related to WPF: in Silverlight for W8/RT localization MUST be via bindings....and if you want to localize the standard "empty content" property, for example, I think it should be done "styling" the control, in a Resource Dictionary......but maybe this is not so for WPF...sorry again, good answer tough